# Full screen background image with 100% height overlay div

Tags: css, background-image

Check out this [picture](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18255104/example.gif) to see what I am trying to accomplish.  Basically I want to use a full screen background image and then overlay a div (in the linked picture, this is the gray area in the middle with the red lines around it) after the logo and nav on the left that will always have a 100% height regardless of scrolling.

The only way I think I can pull this off is to use a background image for the gray area that is repeated vertically, and then make a div for the full screen background image and change the z-indexes around to get the desired layering.

The css I was using for the overlay div was:

```
#overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 360px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But when you have to scroll for larger content, the div always ends at the "fold" and then the background image takes over for the rest of the content.

Are there any tricks I can take advantage of to do this in purely CSS?  Also, I don't want to use CSS3 multiple backgrounds because of cross-browser concerns.

Comment: Looks like that picture isn't public on DropBox. I'm getting a 403

Comment: Fixed it.  Should be working now.

Comment: have you tried changing height to min-height?

Comment: I ended up making this for an answer - but the an answer has already been accepted. I'll leave this here anyway as another way of doing it incase it helps anyone: http://jsfiddle.net/6DHKK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the `height: 100%` and changing the position to relative.

You may need to add some padding and margins to get it exactly how you want but this should just about fix it.